# event.context not set by {{action ...}} when using {{#each ...} (undefined)

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying out Ember.js for the first time by roughly following the Ember.js guide, but I'm running into the following problem.

Relevant code:
https://gist.github.com/3257657 (for complete rails app, see: https://github.com/basveeling/ember-test)

Context:
I'm running the latest ember-rails build with the 1.0 prerelease ember.js. I'm using ember-data for the post model.

Almost everything works in this app, except that the hrefs created by `{{action showPost context="post" href=true}}` have an undefined id (`#/posts/undefined`).
Furthermore, the jQuery event passed to the `showPost` action doesn't have a context property (it does have a view property).

Am I going at this the wrong way, or have I perhaps stumbled on a bug in the prerelease?

edit: this might be related to [Url contains 'undefined' instead of id after navigating back from 'edit' to 'show'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807742/url-contains-undefined-instead-of-id-after-navigating-back-from-edit-to-sho)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try change `{{action showPost context="post" href=true}}` to  `{{action showPost post href=true}}`

The 1.0 prerelease has changed the action helper.

More info: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/83b7a61a892e55423cf1e66f606b13435bcab8f0

Comment: Just tried this: it updates the href (e.g. it now renders to `<a href="#/posts/1" data-ember-action="3">...</a>`), which seems good, however when clicked, it points to #/posts/undefined for some reason. Any ideas?

Edit: woops, forgot to reset the `showPost: function(router,event){...` back to showPost: Ember.Route.transitionTo('posts.show'),. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can even send several context objects now. You will have them in the event.contexts array